# Cannot understand Firebase Auth E-mail login

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm about to go insane. I cannot work my head around how to create a simple email and password login with firebase auth for web.

I have added the code firebase says, with the api key, auth domain etc. to the head tag of my page.

I tried debugging in the console and I get these errors. What do I do? Both shows google urls.
[image]

**EDIT**
The bottom of my code now looks like this, but nothing is added to firebase, I just get the error above:

```html
<form id="app">
<input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><br />
<input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
<button onclick="signIn()">Login</button> <button id="btnLogin">Sign up</button> <button hidden="true" id="btnLogout">Logout</button>
</form>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIz",
    authDomain: "y.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://y.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "y",
    storageBucket: "yn.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script>
(function() {
 
 var app = document.querySelector('#app');
 
 app.signIn = function(){
  var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
     var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
  
  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);
  
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
 }
 

 

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create two variables.  On button click get values of inputs and assign to those variables.  Call `...createUserWithEmailAndPassword(yourEmailVariable, yourPasswordVariable)...`

Comment: @lamelemon I have updated my question. I tried using the console.log(email); to see if I could see what I typed in the email input when I clicked login in the console, but nothing shows?

Comment: Are you running `firebase.initializeApp(config);`? Are you including scripts `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>` in some format? Is your site/server running HTTPS? Show your configuration and initialization please. You can mask the keys if necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I believe I am. Just edited my question so you can see the code.

Comment: It looks like you are. Can you `console.log(error);` inside that `catch()`. This will help provide understanding of what might be happening.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky well when I have the console open, I type in the email and a password. The console is displaying some kind of message, but it is going away in a split second. I do not understand this :( Is there some kind of connection between firebase and my webpage that I am missing??

Comment: The reason for requesting the `console.log(error)` is to understand what the [error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) is that is occurring exactly. You may need to "preserve log" to keep the messages there.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky where do you want the console.log(error)?

Comment: I added the code in the catch, and I am getting these errors:
`[Error] Failed to load resource: annulleret (signupNewUser, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=MYAPIKEYHERE due to access control checks.
[Log] A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. (index.php, line 98)`

Comment: `[Log] O {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.", I: function, toJSON: function} (index.php, line 98)`

Comment: It seems it was because my input fields were inside a <form> tag. I just removed it and was able to create an account?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.value`.

```js
(function() {
 
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
 
  app.signIn = function(){
    var email = app.txtEmail.value;
    var pass = app.txtPassword.value;
  
    // or
    //var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    //var pass = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
    
    console.log(email);
    console.log(pass);
  }
})();
```

```html
<form id="app">
<input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><br />
<input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
<button onclick="app.signIn()">Login</button> <button id="btnLogin">Sign up</button> <button hidden="true" id="btnLogout">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added the `.value;` but still nothing shows in the console :(

Comment: @FeReTu You have another issue then because it works fine in the above snippet.

Comment: What could be wrong then? That is my only javascript code?

Comment: I have added an image of the error I get in the console